# Getting the key_pair name for an aws_instance create

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My goal is to write a Terraform definition that will create a new AWS EC2 instance.  In my AWS project, I *know* that there will be a key pair definition already in place.  I know it will be the *only* key pair definition.  I am not told the name of the key pair.

To create the EC2 instance, I must define:

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  ...
  key_name="<KEY_NAME_STRING>"
  ...
}
```

and in there is my puzzle.  My hope was to use *only* Terraform definitions without user interaction.  At present, I am asking the user to open the AWS console and find the key pair name and edit the Terraform definition with the key pair name that they found.  Ideally, I would like Terraform to interrogate the AWS environment, retrieve a list of the key pairs and choose the first (only) item in the list to use with the instance creation.  Unfortunately, I'm not finding any recipe of technique to achieve this.

Does anyone see any techniques or solutions I might investigate?  Again, let's assume I only have Terraform and no AWS CLI or other tools that wouldn't be available outside of a Terraform environment.

Comment: I assume you can't actually create/manage the key pair using terraform?

Comment: Howdy @pijemcolu ... actually there is indeed a nice mechanism to create a new key pair available in Terraform.  My puzzle is that I have to re-use what is already in place.  The back story is that the AWS environment I need to use comes "partially" preconfigured and the goal is to re-use the existing key pair definition that already exists.  I realize that this is quite a weird story ...  but think of a lab exercise environment where the keys and key pair are pre-provided and the students have to use those (I'm building a Terraform lab for students to use).

Comment: Some terraform providers/resources offer a data source equivalent, which could potentially offer you the ability to read the aws key pair attributes you require. However a data source for aws key pair doesn't exist. 

I therefore believe it's impossible within the constraints you've created for yourself. 

You either:
1. script the finding of the key using AWS CLI either in a null provider or script provider or ...
2. create the key using terraform `aws_key_pair` resource
3. import the key into pre-created terraform resource.